# How do I pass the server ip address in the form parameter correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

I have an application written in fastapi and deployed on the ubuntu server using uvicorn and supervisor.
The command `uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000` starts the application.
And I have access to the application at the address

```
myserver_ip:8000
```

The application has a form that (GET) is displayed at

```
http://myserver_ip:8000/file/



@router.get("/file/")
async def file_receive():
    content = """
<body>
<form action = "http://0.0.0.0:8000/image/uploadfile/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="file" type="file" multiple>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)
```

The action parameter is  `http://0.0.0.0:8000/image/uploadfile/` but after the form redirect, I don't go to the page http://myserver_ip:8000/image/uploadfile/.
The same result if I set `action = http://localhost:8000/image/uploadfile/`

of course, if I set the action variable directly = `http://myserver_ip:8000/image/uploadfile/` all everything starts to work. But then there is no way to run this code on a local machine.
How do I set redirect correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use a relative url?